# Office 365 Mail Send using Application Registration

Tags: node.js, office365

I am trying to send Email from Application Login using NodeJS. I am able to login and can read all users information using Microsoft Graph API. Also, I have explored the Graph API explorer. The problem is I am Unable to send Emails even though i have added API Permissions for the App. I am getting the following error while sending the Request from Axios.

```
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');
require('dotenv').config();
const axios = require('axios');

let accessToken = '';

let mailData = {
  message: {
    subject: 'Meet for lunch?',
    body: {
      contentType: 'Text',
      content: 'The new cafeteria is open.',
    },
    toRecipients: [
      {
        emailAddress: {
          address: '<My users mail ID>',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

async function main() {
  const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      authority: process.env.AAD_ENDPOINT + process.env.TENANT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    },
  };

  const apiConfig = {
    uri: process.env.GRAPH_ENDPOINT + '/users',
  };

  const tokenRequest = {
    scopes: [process.env.GRAPH_ENDPOINT + '.default'],
  };

  const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);
  console.log(msalConfig);
  try {
    const authResponse = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(tokenRequest);
    console.log(authResponse.accessToken); // display access token

    accessToken = authResponse.accessToken;

    //  callApi('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users', accessToken).then((res)=>{
    //   console.log(res.data);
    //  })

    callApiMail('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sendEmail', accessToken).then(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res.response);
        console.log(res.response.data.error.innerError);
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    // console.log(error);
  }
}

async function callApi(endpoint, accessToken) {
  const options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  };

  console.log('request made to web API at: ' + new Date().toString());

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(endpoint, options);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}

async function callApiMail(endpoint, accessToken) {
  const options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  console.log('request made to web API at: ' + new Date().toString());

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(endpoint, mailData, options);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}

main();
```

Result:
data: {
error: {
code: 'BadRequest',
message: "Resource not found for the segment 'sendEmail'.",
innerError: [Object]
}
}

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).